# How to draw math symbols?

Tags: c#, windows, image, math, gdi

I need draw some pictures and save it into a JPG file.

I know that the C# GDI can draw string with method `Graphics.DrawString`.

But what troubles me is that I need draw some math symbols, like below:

[image: some math symbols]

So are there some libraries can help me to do that? How can I get the math symbols with GDI?

Comment: Not GDI, but WPF. Not used it but looks like it might help you: https://launchpad.net/wpf-math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't find a pure .NET solution, I would look for a command-line tool or a native DLL library which can render standard formattings like MathML or LaTeX math expressions. You will find plenty of FOSS stuff for these and I don't think it would be too hard to integrate. In case you work with bitmaps, you can just tell the 3rd party to render a given size bitmap. If you need vectorized drawings, then you could aim to produce your entire output in LaTeX or maybe you can turn MathML/LaTeX formulas to RTF/HTML.

Comment: LaTeX is the best math typesetting software ever written.  The best JavaScript implementation I know of is KaTeX:  https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/